# nginx + php-fpm. How to rewrite?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a following part of host config file.

```
location / {
    try_files           $uri /frontend.php;
}

location /backend/ {
    try_files           $uri /backend.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include             fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass        127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

How can I remove "/backend" from the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] using only nginx rules?

Answer (score 0):

Use map directive to create a new request uri variable and then set fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI using this new variable. Tested and it works.

```
### update REQUEST_URI
map $request_uri $new_request_uri {
  default $request_uri;               # for frontend request, still use $request_uri
  ~^/backend(?P<suffix>.*)$ $suffix;  # for backend request, only use the suffix after "/backend"
}

server {
  ...

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass        127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $new_request_uri;
  }
}
```